# Looking for an efficient way to generate a dict inside pandas column generated from values of other columns

Tags: python, pandas

I am preparing a dataset for an API string.
The dataset has 4-5 million rows.

While preparing the API string, it is necessary to create dicts based on values of the dataset.

I have a working code, using list comprehension, which works fine. But for the dataset it takes about 4-5 minutes cumputing time.

My question is, wether there is an alternative that is more efficient.

This is my code:

```
vDf.loc[vDf['type'].isin(simpleattributes),'valuetext'] = [dict(data=data,locale=locale,scope=scope) 
                                                          for data,locale,scope in zip(
                                                              vDf.loc[vDf['type'].isin(simpleattributes),'data']
                                                              ,vDf.loc[vDf['type'].isin(simpleattributes),'locale']
                                                              ,vDf.loc[vDf['type'].isin(simpleattributes),'scope'])]
```

I was thinking about trying numpy where (np.where):

```
vDf['testdict'] = np.where(vDf['type'].isin(simpleattributes), dict(data=vDf['data'],locale=vDf['locale'],scope=vDf['scope']), "null")
```

But the result is, that a list with all values of the specified columns is returned.

Example Output:

```
Print VDF testdict
{u'locale': [u'null', u'null', u'null', u'null...
{u'locale': [u'null', u'null', u'null', u'null...
{u'locale': [u'null', u'null', u'null', u'null...
{u'locale': [u'null', u'null', u'null', u'null..
```

I tried similar code like above, but so far, only the list comprehension delivers the desired result.
As I'm still new to Python and Pandas, I'm curious to learn, wether there is a more efficient way to generate the dict values.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You want a separate dictionary for each row of that column, right?  There's no short cut that makes multiple dictionaries at once.

Comment: So, that means, my current solution is the best?

Comment: `np.where(cond, A, B)` is a Python expression.  Python evaluates each of the 3 arguments, and THEN passes them to `where`.  The `dict(data=vDf['data'],locale=vDf['locale'],scope=vDf['scope'])` expression crates ONE dictionary, not multiple.  `where` is not a row by row iterator.